# How implement comparator in to sort objects in android or java

Tags: java, android, sorting

Let me start with the following example:

```
public void loadList(ArrayList<Calls> list) {
    List<Calls> calls = new ArrayList<Calls>();
    calls.addAll(list);
}
```

where `Calls` is a simple class:

```
public class Calls {
    public long ms;
    public name;     
}
```

I want to sort the `List<Calls>` above in ascending or descending order based on the `ms` field. I came across some examples of `Comparator` but still am not clear through.

Comment: Which examples you tried? And what is not clear

Comment: There is a method called compare(Object O1, Object O2) in the Comparator interface. You have to override(implement) it. Put your sorting logic in there... Logic is simple... if O1.ms<O2.ms ? return -1 :((O1.ms==O2.ms)?return 0 :return 1)); .. Something like this will help ...NOTE: This is not the exact code...

Comment: @TheLostMind +1 worked perfectly..

Answer (score 16):

I guess this would help

```
public void loadList(ArrayList<Calls> list) {
    List<Calls> calls = new ArrayList<Calls>();
    calls.addAll( list );

    // Ascending Order
    Collections.sort(calls, new Comparator<Calls>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Calls o1, Calls o2) {
            return (int)(o1.ms-o2.ms);
        }
    });
    // Descending Order
    Collections.sort(calls, new Comparator<Calls>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Calls o1, Calls o2) {
            return (int)(o2.ms-o1.ms);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to call youradapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); so that the changes take place immediately.

Answer (score 3):

see following example

```
class CallsComp implements Comparator<Calls>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Calls c1, Calls c2) {
        if(c1.getMs() < c2.getMs()){
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

just implement a Comparator this way:

```
private class CallsComparator implements Comparator<Calls> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Calls calls1, Calls calls2) {
      //Swap calls1 with 2
      return 1;
      //Spap 2 with 1
      return -1;
      // do nothing
      return 0;
    }

  }
```

of course you have to replace my comments with an if-condition :-)

and execute the comparator with:

```
  Collections.sort(calls, new CallsComparator());
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Calls` class need to implement the `Comparable` interface and implement the `compareTo` method:

```
public class Calls implements Comparable<Calls> {
   public long ms;
   public name;

   @Override
   public int compareTo(Calls call) {
       // Prepend a -1 for inverse order
       return Long.compare(this.ms,call.ms);
   }
}
```

Then just call `Collections.sort(calls)` to sort your list.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MSComaparator implements Comparator<Calls>{

        @Override
        public int compare(Calls lhs, Calls rhs) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return lhs.ms-rhs.ms;
        }

    }

    class NameComaparator implements Comparator<Calls>{

        @Override
        public int compare(Calls lhs, Calls rhs) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return lhs.name.comapreTo(rhs.name);
        }

    }
```

and call:

```
public void loadList(ArrayList<Calls> list) {
    List<Calls> calls = new ArrayList<Calls>();
    calls.addAll(list);
    Collections.sort(calls,new MSComaparator())
}
```

if you just want to sort based on ns you can simple implement Comparable:

```
public class Calls implements Comparable<Calls>{
    public long ms;
    public name;     
    @Override
        public int compareTo(Calls  another) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return this.ms>another.ms;
        }
}
```

And call:

```
public void loadList(ArrayList<Calls> list) {
    List<Calls> calls = new ArrayList<Calls>();
    calls.addAll(list);
    Collections.sort(calls)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@ARP

I know its too late to answer this question but I have implemented same thing in my project recently so thought i should share with you

so inside your `function` after adding list what you can do is

```
public void loadList(ArrayList<Calls> list) {
    List<Calls> calls = new ArrayList<Calls>();
    calls.addAll(list);
    Collections.sort(calls, new Comparator<Calls>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Calls o, Calls t1) {
                    return (int) (o.getMS() - t1.getMS());
                }
            });
}
```

This will sort `ArrayList<Calls>` call for you based on the value present in `ms`
.